# Scid vs PC: how to visualize engine line on the board?

Tags: scid

I've installed scid yesterday and was wondering how to visualize an engine line on the board.

My approach is the following: setting up a position on the board by clickng "**Game**" -> "**New Game**", then starting the engine and stoping it after some time.

At "**Analysis**" window you can see variations that the engine came up with. How can I visualize some of these variations? I've tired clicking on "**Add variation**" as well as "**Add variations**" but nothing happened. If I click on "**Add move**" only one move is added (which is logical, haha, bud doesn't give me any clue on how to use this feature).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring up the separate "Analysis board" by clicking on the icon in the strip

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more information to your answer. The analysis board seems not to be interactive and displays variations only during the engine's runtime.